# Review deployment template

Tags: github-actions

[image]

I know that you can have templates for Pull Requests (pull_request_template.md) in GitHub. Is there anything similar for review deployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That window, can't be customized.

You could have an action workflow that creates a proper github issue, assigns it to the reviewer applies a template etc.

That way people could capture their notes in more detail and in a structured way. But then not really a way to enforce this from said window.